# Unknown column in 'order clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this sql request:

```
SET @C := 0;

SELECT _s.*, @C := @C + 1 AS `number` FROM `server` _s
INNER JOIN servers_services _ss ON (_s.id = _ss.server_id)
INNER JOIN service _s2 ON (_ss.service_id = _s2.id)
WHERE _s.is_vip != 0 AND _s.is_hidden != 1 AND _s.is_banned != 1

UNION

SELECT _s.*, @C := @C + 1 AS `number` FROM `server` _s
INNER JOIN servers_services _ss ON (_s.id = _ss.server_id)
INNER JOIN service _s2 ON (_ss.service_id = _s2.id)
WHERE _s.is_vip != 0 AND _s.is_hidden != 1 AND _s.is_banned != 1

ORDER BY _s2.priority DESC
```

output error:

> 1054 - Unknown column '_s2.priority' in 'order clause'

Comment: where of second SELECT request will be follow:
WHERE _s.is_vip != 1 AND _s.is_hidden != 1 AND _s.is_banned != 1

Comment: When ORDER BY and UNION, only selected columns can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
select * from (
SELECT _s.*, @C := @C + 1 AS `number` FROM `server` _s
INNER JOIN servers_services _ss ON (_s.id = _ss.server_id)
INNER JOIN service _s2 ON (_ss.service_id = _s2.id)
WHERE _s.is_vip != 0 AND _s.is_hidden != 1 AND _s.is_banned != 1

UNION

SELECT _s.*, @C := @C + 1 AS `number` FROM `server` _s
INNER JOIN servers_services _ss ON (_s.id = _ss.server_id)
INNER JOIN service _s2 ON (_ss.service_id = _s2.id)
WHERE _s.is_vip != 0 AND _s.is_hidden != 1 AND _s.is_banned != 1
) t

ORDER BY priority DESC
```